# sql count in joined tables gives errors on GROUP BY

Tags: asp.net, join, count, group-by, sql-server-express

I am stuck on SELECT query with COUNT on joined tables. I am developping in Visual Studio 2015, asp.net using VB.net and SQL Server Express x86 (SQL Server 12.0.2269).

This are the tables:

```
Products

 - Id (PK, int, not null)
 - Number (varchar(20), not null)
 - CategoryId (int, not null)
 - Name (varchar(50), not null)
 - Description (text, not null)
 - IsActive (bit, not null)
 - Stock (int, not null)
 - SetColors (bit, not null)
 - SetSizes (bit, not null)
 - MakeId (FK, int, null)
 - StockTypeId (FK, int, not null)

Groups

 - Id (PK, FK, int, not null)
 - Name (varchar(50), not null)
 - Description (text, null)
 - Picture (image, null)

ProductGroups

 - Id (PK, int, not null)
 - ProductId (FK, int, not null)
 - GroupId (FK, int, not null)
```

Each Product can belong to one or more Groups, what is held in the ProductGroups table.

I need a query to select Groups.Id, Groups.Name, Groups.Picture and a count of the products belonging to each group for showing in a databound asp:ListView.

What ever I try, I get errors on the Name and Picture column, because they are "*not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause*".

I have been searching on the internet for solutions. This is the last query I tried:

```
SELECT g.Id, g.Name, g.Picture, COUNT(DISTINCT pg.ProductId) as numProd
FROM Groups g 
LEFT JOIN ProductGroups pg ON g.Id = pg.GroupId 
GROUP BY g.Id, g.Name, g.Picture, pg.ProductId
```

I don't know what aggregate function I should use on varchar or nullable image fields and grouping on image is not allowed either "*The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator*").

Anyone who can help me to solve this?

In a second step I will also need to filter on StockTypeId, MakeId, CategoryId, isActive and Stock. But that will be easy when the first step should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query will do the trick:

```
SELECT g.Id, g.Name, g.Picture, pg.pg_count
FROM Groups g
JOIN (Select GroupId, Count(*) as pg_count
   FROM ProductGroups Group By GroupId) pg on g.Id = pg.GroupId
```

Comment: Yeah, anytime you found yourself grouping by a name or description field, you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, unless there is an issue with your tables relation:

> `SELECT g.Id, g.Name, g.Picture, COUNT(DISTINCT pg.ProductId) asnumProd 
>   FROM Groups g  LEFT JOIN ProductGroups pg ON g.Id = pg.GroupId
>   GROUP BY g.Id, g.Name, g.Picture`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I run this query, I got again the error _Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 3: The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator._
Maybe I should check my relations, they were created by the entityframework.

Comment: oh g.Picture is throwing you off

Comment: do you need the Picture data?

Comment: Yes, because I need the picture to show for each group, with the name over it and a badge with the number of products found. Thanks anyway for helping!